# cv2 findchessboardcorners order of corners not consistent

Tags: opencv, opencv-solvepnp

I am going to use solvepnp function to get the rotation and translation matrices for target to camera cordinate transformation. However, when I run the same chessborad image (multiple poses), I realized the order of corners found by the cv2.findchessboardcorners are not consistent.  I thought this would affect the result of solvepnp. Any idea whether that's the case? or if it is, is there an easy fix? the order is switched between two orders as in the following two images.
used the below code to number the corners
`

```
img = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, CHECKERBOARD, corners2, ret)
n=0
for i in range(0,21):
    img=cv2.putText(img,str(n), (int(corners2[i,0,0]),int(corners2[i,0,1])),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2,(0,255,255),1,2)
    n+=1
```

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Comment: Sure this affects solvePnp. Your pattern is ambiguous. Just from looking at the images I wouldnt know whether you've turned the camera by 180°. You could add some additional markers like QR codes to define a unique orientation.

Comment: Thanks a lot!, yes I can include something to show the orientation. Would findchessboardcorners automatically recognize the orientation when that confusion is removed. or I need to program something?

Comment: a checkerboard is always ambiguous in 180° rotation, so you will have to program your own method in correcting the orientation once you KNOW the orientation. I guess built-in orientation without ambiguity is given by charuco patterns.

Comment: Or possible to write simple tracking (if you cant change pattern). You can check 2 orders and find closest to previous order.

Comment: Thanks for all the helpful suggestions